# admin.php:26 Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined

Tags: javascript, maps

everytime i make `var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();` in console i got admin.php:26 Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined. can somebody help me fix this?

```
<script>
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var directionsDisplay;

  function loadScript(){
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA6FWEcLI-sIDj2ViI02kjL3KV-njatBro&sensor=false&callback=initMap";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }
  window.onload = loadScript;
  ....
    </script>
```

Comment: pls provide your html

Comment: i edited it sorry @AnikIslamAbhi

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the maps app before you load it and then not providing the callback function. Try this:

```
<script>
  function loadScript(){
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA6FWEcLI-sIDj2ViI02kjL3KV-njatBro&sensor=false&callback=initMap";
    document.body.appendChild(script);

  }
  window.onload = loadScript;

  function initMap() {
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService(document.getElementById('map'));
    var directionsDisplay;
    console.log( 'Script loaded.' );
  }
</script>
```

Comment: it doesn't work. still give google is not defined :(